# Is there a way to generate and print pi to the nth digit in Java>

Tags: java

Alright, I am pretty new to coding and have always been interested in numbers, so I thought I might try to create a code to generate and print "n" numbers of pi.

After a bit of research all I could find was ways to calculate pi without using built in functions like Math.PI, but nothing in java to actually print pi to a number of digits greater than 16.

The code I quickly made was this

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.System;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class piDisplay {

public static void main (String args[]) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList <Integer> piDigit = new ArrayList <Integer>();

    double test = Math.PI;
    System.out.print(test);

    int numDigits = scan.nextInt();
    double pi = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < numDigits; i++) {

        pi += (1/Math.pow(16, (double)i))*(4/(double)((i*8)+1)-2/(double)((i*8)+4)-1/(double)((i*8)+5)-1/(double)((i*8)+6));

        //adds each individual digit to an array
        piDigit.add((int)((pi*Math.pow(10, i))%10));

        System.out.println(pi);
        System.out.println(piDigit.toString());
    }
}
}
```

It uses the BBP formula to calculate pi, but I just don't know how I would go about printing more than 16 digits, if there is even a way to do that in java (there probably is).

Any input is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You could use a BigDecimal class to get around hardware limitations, or bake your own more focussed task.